# Token based authentication from class library to mvc5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

I have mvc5 application with custom login implementation. Once i got the credentials from user am making post and getting the token to validate the user. **Owin Token implementation in separate class library project.**

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(UserLoginViewModel model)
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:4312";
            Token token = new Token();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var form = new Dictionary<string, string> 
               { 
                   {"grant_type", "password"}, 
                   {"username", "jignesh"}, 
                   {"password", "user123456"}, 
               };
                var tokenResponse = client.PostAsync(baseAddress + "/otoken", new FormUrlEncodedContent(form)).Result;
                //var token = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                token = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<Token>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;
               ........
            }
    }
```

I am not sure how to make call /trigger the token implementation in class library project from mvc application. because class library project is not executable project. is it possible way of implementing token based implementation in separate class lib and make use of that implementation in different application (mvc and webapi).

my layer

**UI(MVC) -> Authentication project (Owin class libarary) -> entity framework**

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need to expose your application login through an API of some sort.

For example you can create a token server which is responsible for authentication of both your API and you MVC project - an external provider - like Google or Facebook for example.

This is also the best way to share the same token between your two applications (MVC and API).

Check [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/) article, it's extremely clear.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: how we can call the token in class libarary. because class library won't be called.only web project we can able to call right ? then how it is possible to call the token implementation in class library

Comment: You need to expose your class library with an API. That's for sure. What you can do is to share the class library between MVC and API and expose the token endpoint in both of them. OR, better, create a THIRD API and use it as resource server, and use that API to authenticate both your MVC and API. Check the link!

Comment: Is it possible to use both Db authentication and active directory authentication combined in single sample?

Answer (score 0):

For token based authentication, you need to use configure your mvc application or webapi to issue token. class library cannot issue token.The primary reason is that, you need to call the url configured to fetch the token eg.http://localhost:8080/api/gettoken.
So, either use webapi to issue token or mvc app to issue token.

Comment: but i want to move the authentcation logic in seprate project inorder to use both mvc and webapi application

Comment: Why do you need to use both mvc and webapi to issue tokens?Even if you move your logic to separate dll, only one of it can issue token, not both.If you want authentication for both, then use forms authentication for mvc and token for webapi. So, once you login, after user is authenticated in mvc, then make a request to webapi to get the token.